# Rendering performance issue with an object displayed with three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm rendering an obj file (from blender) with Three.js and the problem I have is that animation is slowing down with time (rather dramaticaly !).

Here is the code I use :

```
<script>

            var objcontainer, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            init(); 
            animate();


            function init() {

                objcontainer = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( objcontainer );

                // scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 300;
                camera.position.x = 0;
                camera.position.y = 0;
                scene.add( camera );

                /*var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
                scene.add( ambient );*/

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                directionalLight.position.set( 1, 1, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
                loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
                    var object = event.content;

                    object.position.y = 20;
                    object.position.x = 0;
                    object.position.z = 0;
                    object.rotation.x = -(Math.PI / 2);
                    scene.add( object );
                }, false);
                loader.load('objects/coque.obj', 'objects/coque.mtl');
                loader.load('objects/ecran_int.obj', 'objects/ecran_int.mtl');
                loader.load('objects/ecran_tour.obj', 'objects/ecran_tour.mtl');
                loader.load('objects/app_photo.obj', 'objects/app_photo.mtl');


                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                    antialias       : true // to get smoother output
                });
                renderer.setClearColorHex( 0xe5e5e5, 1 );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                objcontainer.appendChild( renderer.domElement );            
            }

            $('#left').bind('mouseenter', function() {
                this.iid = setInterval(function() {
                camera.position.x = camera.position.x + 10;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.clear();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );                 
            }, 25);
            }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
                this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
            });


            $('#right').bind('mouseenter', function() {
                this.iid = setInterval(function() {
                camera.position.x = camera.position.x - 10;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.clear();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );              
            }, 25);
            }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
                this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
            });

            $('#up').bind('mouseenter', function() {
                this.iid = setInterval(function() {
                camera.position.y = camera.position.y - 10;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.clear();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );              
            }, 25);
            }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
                this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
            });

            $('#down').bind('mouseenter', function() {
                this.iid = setInterval(function() {
                camera.position.y = camera.position.y + 10;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.clear();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );              
            }, 25);
            }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
                this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
            });

            $('#zoom-in').bind('mouseenter', function() {
                this.iid = setInterval(function() {
                camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 10;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.clear();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );              
            }, 25);
            }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
                this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
            });

            $('#zoom-out').bind('mouseenter', function() {
                this.iid = setInterval(function() {
                camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 10;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.clear();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );              
            }, 25);
            }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
                this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
            });

            $('#init').bind('click', function() {
                camera.position.z = 300;
                camera.position.x = 0;
                camera.position.y = 20;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.clear();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );              
            });

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }

            function render() { 
                requestAnimationFrame(render); 
                renderer.render(scene, camera); 
            } 

        </script>
```

On Safari, performance decrease a little bit slower, on Chrome it's fast.

Any help is appreciated :)

Geoffrey

Comment: Please sort out the tabbing in your code. It's shifted to the right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jsfiddle would make it easier to debug. But I highly suspect it is because you are calling render() from your event handler setInterval functions. This should not be necessary at all, as you are already rendering each frame in your animate function.

I think your code makes it so that the scene is rendered multiple times for each frame, as the intervals are not cleared properly. That would explain why it slows over time; the amount of redundant render() calls keep growing...

Try just removing all the

```
            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

From your event handlers/setintervals.

EDIT: You could check some of the controls files (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/FirstPersonControls.js) on how they implement movement(animation) with event handlers. No logic happens at the events, they only set a variable like `movingForward = true;`. The actual movement is then done in a single update() loop. This kind of approach might be better in your case too.

EDIT #2: Actually just noticed your main animation loop is setup incorrectly, which might be the main issue (the stuff about event handler is still worth considering). It also causes redundant render calls. Try removing the requestAnimationFrame call from your render() function, as you already do it in animate().

```
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }

        function render() { 
            // requestAnimationFrame(render); <-- remove this
            renderer.render(scene, camera); 
        }
```

Comment: You are my hero :) EDIT #2 made it !